# Is it possible to detect when an onscreen keyboard has finished closing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a mobile site with inputs for text. After the user finishes entering text, they press a button to proceed. The screen is then redrawn. However the redraw process that happens requires knowledge of the window size before it does its thing (it involves canvas stuff).  The problem is that the keyboard has not finished closing when the redraw happens and so the window size is reported incorrectly. Is there anyway to detect when the window has finished closing? Such as an event?

Comment: Couldn't you simply use the `resize` DOM event? If re-drawing is expensive, maybe consider using a timeout instead of doing it right away.

Comment: @user1421750 A timeout would be a bad idea as slow phones will take longer and I have no way of knowing when it will have finished. I want the experience to be zippy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an event on the operative system layer, and I guess there is no way of getting it from the browser unless you are developing an hybrid application and you can use some native bridging library like Phonegap/Cordova.

However, I think the answer you are looking for lies in your question: monitoring the height of the window you should be able to understand when a user has opened or closed the onscreen keyboard.

Comment: Ok, I;ll go with that. I can make a note of the screen size before the keyboard appears, so I should be able to work out when it has returned to that size. I was just hoping there was a better way!

Comment: Sure, feel free to leave the question open for some time, maybe someone will come with a better idea.

Comment: No need for the attitude! When I upvoted it, it had not opened up for an accepted answer yet.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.